# SO Developer jobs issue with sending applications

Tags: support, bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs

Whenever I send an application to a company via developer jobs, it seems my application goes to other companies where I previously applied. One company has a page where you can see your applications. I see there that I apparently applied 9 times! Initially I thought it was a bug on their side, but today, when I sent my application to the another company, I got email confirmation from them and from two others companies where I applied previously! Is developer jobs broken in some twisted way?

Comment: Sounds like SO **really** wants you to get a job :P

Comment: @AndréKool Or doesn't, applying 9 times for the same job is pretty desperate after all!

Comment: we're looking into it, stay tuned ;)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Fun fact: under certain specific circumstances we would resend all of your existing job applications every time you applied for any job. So your application get duplicated nine times because you'd applied for nine jobs since then.

Those specific circumstances were:

- The employer was using a third-party applicant tracking system such as Greenhouse,
- You were located geographically outside the country where the job was located, and
- It's not a Friday. Yes, really.

We'd actually had a couple of bug reports from employers about this too, but I was only able to figure out what was going on after looking at your application history. Thanks for reporting it!

My esteemed colleague @g3rv4 is deploying the fix to production as I write.

Comment: Are you sure [Iceland](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/54746/158100) isn't involved?

Comment: Wow, the "it's not a Friday" killed me :) I'm glad it got fixed and I could help, I just hope it won't/didn't make my potential employers angry.